# Get quartile of last value compared to last column per row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

| index | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 31 | 45 | 9 | 30 |
| B | 0 | 12 |  |  |  |
| C | 3 | 5 | 3 | 3 |  |
| D | 2 | 2 | 3 | 16 | 14 |
| E | 0 | 0 | 56 |  |  |

I want to rank the last non-blank value against its column as a quartile. So, for example I'd like to rank A's 30 against all of May (in this case 100%).

| Index | quartile of last value compared to last column per row |
| --- | --- |
| A | 100% |
| B | 80% |
| C | 33.3% |
| D | 50% |
| E | 100% |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first rank and then use `pd.Series.last_valid_index` to get the last valid values.

```
df.rank(pct=True).mul(100).apply(lambda x: x[x.last_valid_index()], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
A    100.000000
B     80.000000
C     33.333333
D     50.000000
E    100.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to build the quantile table, then look up with `pd.merge_asof`:

```
last_values = (df.rename_axis(columns='month').stack()
                 .reset_index(name='val')
                 .drop_duplicates('index',keep='last').sort_values('val')
              )

quantiles = (df.apply(pd.Series.quantile, q=np.arange(101)/100)
                .rename_axis(columns='month',index='quantile').stack()
                .reset_index(name='val').sort_values('val')
            )


pd.merge_asof(last_values, quantiles,
              by='month', on='val').sort_values('index')
```

Output:

```
  index month   val  quantile
3    A    May  30.0      1.00
1    B    Feb  12.0      0.75
0    C    Apr   3.0      0.00
2    D    May  14.0      0.00
4    E    Mar  56.0      1.00
```